# Is it possible to have a pivot table slicer sort largest to smallest?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have created a new table with Gain and Loss.  My goal is to have gain sort the table from largest to smallest & Loss sort smallest to largest.  I have tried some vba, but unable to sort the value.

```
Sub Macro1() 

Dim wb As Workbook 
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim targetTable As ListObject 
Set wb = ThisWorkbook 
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Project Dash") 

If Worksheets("Project Dash").SlicerCaches("Slicer_Gains__Losses") .SlicerItems("Gai‌​ns").Selected = True Then 

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ProjectGain20").PivotFields("Projec‌​t").AutoSort _ xlDescending, "Sum of Work Variance", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ProjectGain20"). _ PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1), 1 

End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps show your table and your expected outcome and describe what you have tried so far? And if there is code, include enough to be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is there an easier way to create a slicer to invert data from ascending to descending.  I thought it would be easy to have a slicer for sorting from largest to smallest and vice versa.

Comment: Hi, why don't you do sorting via the pivottable? You could tie this to a button. A slicer is to ["slice"](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-slicers-to-filter-data-249F966B-A9D5-4B0F-B31A-12651785D29D) not sort. To that end, you could record a macro doing the sort ascending and descending on the field of interest then link that code to [option buttons](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-check-box-or-option-button-form-controls-9f201e46-8f6b-4a9d-a320-f44b28088cb0), for example, with labels sort ascending/descending.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using Option buttons to sort the backing table instead. A slicer is meant to **filter** your data not to order it. When you add the form control radio/option buttons you need to edit the text, as shown in my image, and then right click each one and associate each button with the macro `CheckOptions`. Here the field being sorted is `[Value1]` which you would change as appropriate. Your data needs to be set up as a table, as shown in the image.

I have used a suggestion by [@L42](http://'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657944/detect-if-a-form-control-option-button-is-selected-in-vba) to do a check on which option button called the macro.

The sort order enumerations are given [here](http://'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlsortorder-enumeration-excel).

[image: Table set up and form control option buttons]

Code to go in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CheckOptions()                        

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim targetTable As ListObject

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change as appropriate
    Set targetTable = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

    Select Case Application.Caller

    Case "Option Button 1"

        SortTable targetTable, 2

    Case "Option Button 2"

        SortTable targetTable, 1

    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub SortTable(ByRef targetTable As ListObject, ByVal myOrder As Byte) 'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlsortorder-enumeration-excel

    With targetTable.Sort

        .SortFields.Clear

        .SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Value1]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, order:= _
                   myOrder, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Slicers are not for sorting. Try an implementation such as i have given in the answer. With a few lines of code changed you could tie this to different kinds of buttons. Or even look into linking to a change event.

Comment: Is it possible to tie the slicer buttons to the action of sorting?  I have tried identifying the slicer name and filed/item without success.

Comment: Slicers filter on existing fields i.e. items in your backing data. Slicer changes can be captured especially via associated pivottable update events. So you could try and hook in to that but i really can't see why you would want to do this. Simply target the source pivot - it is much easier and designed with sorting functionality.

Comment: I created a new table with 3 rows.  1. Gains - Losses 2. Gains 3. Losses  Then a created a slicer from that, but it is tied to no data.  I was attempting to use VBA to link it to another pivot table sort order.  If Slicer_Gains_Losses.slicer.field ("Gains") = True then sort ascending type statement.

Comment: I appreciate your time and Sub above.  I have other slicers on the dashboard and was hoping to be consistent.  Thank you again for your code and discussion.

Comment: Is it possible to use a repeated invisible character like Unichar(12288), and set it to repeat x1,x2 .... depending on the order you want? I tried with 12288 and even though it's vizible in the filder, the Slicer ignores it, but maybe there is a different invizible character that i'm missing.